# Rearranging data frame after combining two data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have two CSV files- file1, file2. File2 is a subset of file1. I would like to merge the content of file2 in file1 and put the entries of file2 at the bottom of file1 so that the total number of entries in file1 remain same after merging.

Here is what I have tried so far but it is basically adding the entries of file2 at the bottom of file1 increasing the number of entries in file1.

```py
data1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
data1 = data1.set_index('entry_id')
data2 = data2.set_index('entry_id')
new = pd.concat([data1,data2])
new = pd.merge(data1,data2, on=['entry_id'])
new = data1 + data2
new = new.drop(['columnC','columnD'],axis =1)
new
```

Comment: Some sample data would be useful if you can provide any. I'm not sure what you mean by "entries". Is this columns or rows? Are you updating the data within file1?

Answer (score 0):

Try `data1.update(data2)`.

The join is on index and update is *in place*.

In future questions include sample data for source DataFrames and expected result.

## Edit

If you want to have first "original" (not updated) rows from
*data1* and **after them** the updated rows from *data2*,
then take different approach:

Start from dropping from *data1* rows with *entry_id* present in *data2*
(which are to be moved to the end of the result):

```
data1.drop(index=data2.index, inplace=True)
```

Then just add rows from *data2*:

```
new = pd.concat([data1,data2])
```

If you want to have *data1* unchanged, then you can do the whole processing
with a **single** instruction:

```
new = pd.concat([data1.drop(index=data2.index), data2])
```

Comment: It just replaces the rows of file2 on top of file1

Answer (score 0):

I guess `merge` is not what you want but the `reindex` function. Since `file2` is a subset of `file1` then there is no necessity to merge as what you want is just to put the `file2` at the bottom of `file1`. `reindex` can help you rearange the rows/columns.

Here is a simple example:

```
d1=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5],'type':[7,8,9,0,1]})
d2=d1[2:4]
d2.index=range(d2.shape[0])
dex1=list(d1[~d1.id.isin(d2.id)].index)
dex2=list(d1[d1.id.isin(d2.id)].index)
d1.reindex(dex1+dex2)
```

`d1` is :

```
d1
Out[51]: 
   id  type
0   1     7
1   2     8
2   3     9
3   4     0
4   5     1
```

`d2` is :

```
d2

Out[50]: 
   id  type
0   3     9
1   4     0
```

The result is :

```
Out[52]: 
   id  type
0   1     7
1   2     8
4   5     1
2   3     9
3   4     0
```

Comment: Same result, rows of file2 replaces the top rows of file1 resulting the same id appears twice in file1